# Knockout data-bind attribute added dynamically does not trigger the click event handler

Tags: knockout.js

In the viewAttached event of my viewmodel, I am creating a dynamic anchor element as follows:

```
 qaItemLink = document.createElement("a");
 $(qaItemLink).attr({ 'class': 'qaTreeItem', 'href': '#', 'data-bind': 'click:$root.showQaItemDetails' });
```

which when checked in UI is rendered as below:

```
<a class="qaTreeItem" href="#" data-bind="click:$root.showQaItemDetails">Item 1</a>
```

I don't see any problem in the anchor tag being rendered. What could be the reason that the function showQaItemDetails is not getting called ?

Comment: are you creating these anchor tags before or after applying the bindings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the element was added after `ko.applyBindings` was called, then Knockout would not have had a chance to bind it. If you are using the `template` binding (or `with`, `foreach`, etc.) to add dynamic content, then Knockout takes care of this for you.  This is generally the best approach.

In your case, if possible, you could wait to call `ko.applyBindings` until the content has been added.

You can also directly bind an element by calling `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element)`. This will bind the element and its children. However, I don't know in your case what context your anchor needs to be bound against (root vs. some nested item).

It is also possible to use `ko.applyBindingsToNode` (or in 3.0 `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` passing a function that returns the binding) to directly apply a binding like:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(qaItemLink, { click: viewModel.showQaItemDetails }, optionalContext);
```

Comment: ko.applyBindingsToNode method worked for me. Instead of calling this method, the other way I can make the click event handler fire is by using jquery using the ".on" as jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.qaTreeItem', function (event) {}); Do you think using jQuery is better than using ko.applyBindingsToNode explicitly ?

Comment: One strange observation. When I execute ko.applyBindingsToNode(qaItemLink, { click: vm.showQaItemDetails(1), text: qaItem }); with a parameter passed, then the method does not get fired on click.

Comment: You need to pass a function reference itself, rather than executing a function with a parameter.  You can potentially use jQuery to handle this click. The examples on this page are helpful: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about durandal, so this might be off base...but the best knockout approach is to avoid using jQuery in your viewmodels and instead writing knockout templates, or data bindings to do the dom manipulation. rp-niemeyer is spot on if you can't use knockout templates for some reason. I made up a contrived example for you.

```
function MapItem(item) {
    item.Name = ko.observable(item.Name);
}
function viewmodel(serverItems) { 
    var self = this;
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(serverItems,MapItem))
    self.SelectedItem = ko.observable(null)
    self.SelectItem = function(item) {
        self.SelectedItem(item);
    }

}
```

with a template like this

```
<div class="view">
    <ul data-bind="foreach:Items">
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:Name,click:$root.SelectItem"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="SelectedItemContainer" >
        <p data-bind="visible:SelectedItem() == null">Select an item from the list</p>
        <div class="SelectedItem" data-bind="with:SelectedItem">
          <h1 data-bind="text:Name"></h1>
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```